# Disable pacman progress bar

Tags: bash, command-line, config, configuration-files, rc

I see
[`pacman`](http://archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html)
has this option

```
--noprogressbar  do not show a progress bar when downloading files
```

That applies to `pacman -S` `pacman -R` `pacman -U`. However I would like to always use this option when appropriate. Is that possible?

Comment: So any time either an -S, -R, or -U flag is passed, automatically append `--noprogressbar`?

Comment: Create an alias for `pacman --noprogressbar` instead and use that.  If the option is incompatible with other options chosen, it should be discarded.

Comment: @devnull I tried that already. It is not discarded in all situations that it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a function in one of your bash files. Something like

```
pacman() {
  [[ $@ =~ -[RSU] ]] && set -- "$@" --noprogressbar
  command pacman "$@"
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this will append `--noprogressbar` any time any of the arguments contains `-R`, `-S`, or `-U`. It will misbehave if the `-S` option is not specified as `-S` (for example, if `--sync` is used, or if `-yS` is used (not sure if pacman supports that last one)). It will also misbehave if any of the non-options happen to contain `-S`, as a package name might, even though Arch don't seem to do that themselves.